# 1px white line when using 2D transforms

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a background image, and hovering on it will scale and rotate with CSS 2D transforms. Everything works fine, except a white gap line of 1px, which looks terrible. This doesn't happen just in Chrome, but almost all browsers. I've tried the following, but without success:

- adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the image div and/or
  its wrapper
- adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0)` to the image div and/or its wrapper
- trying different `display` values
- trying different `position` values

I think this problem only persists when using `overflow: hidden`.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="article col-xs-4">
    <div class="article-overlay"></div>

    <div class="article-content">
        <h2>Learn the skills to land your dream job</h2>
        <h6>Education / Academy</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="article-image" style="background-image: url('assets/images/ed1.jpg')"></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#main-content .education .article {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-content .education .article .article-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#main-content .education .article:hover .article-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

#main-content .education .article .article-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#main-content .education .article:hover .article-image {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(2deg);
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(2deg);
}

#main-content .education .article .article-content {
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

#main-content .education .article .article-content h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

#main-content .education .article .article-content h2:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #bedb39;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}

#main-content .education .article .article-content h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

#main-content .education .article .article-content h6:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

Live demo:

http://amarsyla.com/sandbox/codo/education.html

Comment: Your live demo doesn't seem to match up with you have here. I can't find any elements with a class of "education". Where should the user be hovering to see these transforms?

Comment: @D-Jones I'm sorry, I updated the link.

Comment: No worries! I'm still not seeing the 1px gap though. What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @D-Jones I'm using Chrome 44.0.2403.18 on Windows 8.1 64-bit. This problem occurred on a MacBook Air Safari, and also on Internet Explorer 10 and 11. I think this problem is only with small screens. I don't see it in a large one. Can you please resize your browser window?

Comment: This issue occurs for me on Firefox 38.0.1 and with a screen resolution of 1600 x 1200 on windows 7 professional. This issue occurs only on the left hand side of the right hand side swimming (or flying?) image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, its becouse of z-index, clear z-index from `#main-content .education .article` and you can set z-index to `.logo` and `.social-icons` for example 20 for bringing to front.

```
#main-content .education .article {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header .logo, #header .social-icons  {
    z-index: 20;
}
```